# how to get screenshot on rotation of UIView in swift

Tags: ios, swift, screenshot

I have a UIView which can be resizable and rotatable and I have a UIImageView which frame is equal to superview.I am moving, resizing and rotating UIView based on that I want to take screenshot am able to take screen short from image when there is no rotation but when I rotate that UIView I am not getting the proper screen short from image below is my code for implementing screenshot.

```
 func getscreenshort(points:CGPoint) -> Void {

        for i in 0..<self.arrayOfViewObject.count {

            let userResizeView:ResizableView = arrayOfViewObject[i] as! ResizableView

            self.viewDidLayoutSubviews()

            self.view.layoutIfNeeded()

            var grabRect: CGRect? =  nil

            for imageVar in userResizeView.subviews {

                if imageVar.isKind(of: type(of: UIImageView())  as AnyClass) {

                    if imageVar.tag == userResizeView.tag {

                        grabRect = CGRect(x: userResizeView.frame.origin.x + 5, y: userResizeView.frame.origin.y + 5, width: imageVar.frame.size.width, height: imageVar.frame.size.height)

                    }

                }

            }

            if  UIScreen.main.responds(to: #selector(NSDecimalNumberBehaviors.scale)) {

                UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions((grabRect?.size)!, false, UIScreen.main.scale)

            } else {

                UIGraphicsBeginImageContext((grabRect?.size)!)

            }

            let ctx: CGContext = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!

            ctx.translateBy(x: -(grabRect?.origin.x)!, y: -(grabRect?.origin.y)!)

            imageView.layer.render(in: ctx)

            let viewImage: UIImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()!

            UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

        }

    }
```

This is the issue I am getting.

[image: This is the issue]

Can anyone please help me with the code to get the screenshot when I rotate UIView?

Comment: What is wrong with your screenshot? Can you provide us with a wrong one?

Comment: I have updated my question with screenshot.

Comment: And what would you expect to be the screenshot?

Comment: I need to get screenshot exactly from four gray coloured circular view

Comment: My best guess is that you are screenshotting the `imageView` instead of the small view by doing `imageView.layer.render(in: ctx)`. Use your small view here.